# Feature-image not showing for posts Jekyll

Tags: image, jekyll

I am building a Jekyll site and would like to have feature-imgs on posts show page. I thought I had the Front matter correct with the right file path to my image but for some reason the image still won't show up.

Front matter

```
---
layout: post
title: My Coding Journey
feature-img: "/img/journey.png"
---
```

My images are in a folder in project root called img.

Post layout:

```
---
layout: post-header
---
<article {% if page.feature-img %} class="feature-image"{% endif %}>
  <section class="post-content">{{ content }}</section>
</article>

<!-- Disqus -->
{% if site.theme_settings.disqus_shortname %}
<div class="comments">
  {% include disqus.html %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Any idea why the feature image is not working.

Comment: Does this solve your problem `feature-img: "./img/journey.png"` ? I added a period in front of the image path.

Comment: No. That didn't work, thanks though.

Comment: try something like this `feature-img: "./../img/journey.png"` or this `feature-img: "./../../img/journey.png"`

Comment: Did any of those work?

Comment: No, they didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `img` tag to render the image.

```
---
layout: post
title: My Coding Journey
feature-img: "/img/journey.png"
---
```

and in the layout...

```
<article>
  {% if page.feature-img %}
    <img class="feature-image" src={{ page.feature-img }} alt="Feature Image"/>
  {% endif %}
  <section class="post-content">{{ content }}</section>
</article>
```

Comment: where have they mentioned that you can use `-` as a separator in variables?

Comment: I went ahead and made the adjustments. Still no change. I was misunderstanding your suggestion. Thank you though.

Comment: just realised you dont have an `img` tag to render the image. This is better than using `background-image` in CSS.. Updated the answer..

Comment: It works with a 'minus' character, while your answer suggests it does not. Can you change that please?

Comment: Apparently, it does work with the `-` as well.. TIL..!! Thanks :) Corrected answer..

Comment: Ahh ha. That was the problem. I implemented the fix above, and had to access the file with:  feature-img: "../../../img/journey.jpg" Thanks again to all!